# Perform ACTION_CALL on locked phone

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreenwidget

I'm developing an app with a widget. Now I've my widget on the lockscreen and I need to make a call when the user taps on widget. Is it possible to do that with locked screen? Is there a permission for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should consider using [`ACTION_DIAL`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL). It doesn't need any additional permissions like `ACTION_CALL`. I am not sure the behavior from the lock screen though.

Comment: It is definitely  possible, probably you need to look how this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.dialerWidget thing works.

Comment: I've tried to ACTION_DIAL, but also requires unlock the phone.
¿Which permission is this app using?